# react-native：block logic code block animatioin execution of dropping frames

Tags: react-native, animation

I create a Loading animation with `animated` api of `react-native`, and page navigate other page util block code which come from 3rd library execution completed.

Now, loading animation stop while logic code is running, and loading restart after logic code finish, as I commented out a piece of code that navigate other page from one.

How can i optimize the performance of animation？

1. I can't edit block code which come from 3rd library.
2. I use `useNativeDriver` to support Native Driver.
3. No lottie animation support, and it seems work well.
4. Block logic code and animation are executed at the same time.

```
import EStyleSheet from "react-native-extended-stylesheet";
import LoadingStyles from '../../styles/loading.component'
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native'
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import Svg, { Circle } from 'react-native-svg'
const CircleAnimateClip = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle)
export default function Loading() {
  const animationRef = useRef({
    strokeDashoffset: new Animated.Value(240),
    rotateZ: new Animated.Value(1)
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    const animationDef = () => {
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.strokeDashoffset,
              {
                toValue: 240,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 900
              }
            ),
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.rotateZ,
              {
                toValue: 2,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 900
              }
            ),
          ]),
          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.strokeDashoffset,
              {
                toValue: 200,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 100
              }
            ),
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.rotateZ,
              {
                toValue: 3,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 100
              }
            ),
          ]),
          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.strokeDashoffset,
              {
                toValue: 200,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 900
              }
            ),
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.rotateZ,
              {
                toValue: 4,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 900
              }
            ),
          ]),
          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.strokeDashoffset,
              {
                toValue: 240,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 100
              }
            ),
            Animated.timing(
              animationRef.current.rotateZ,
              {
                toValue: 5,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
                duration: 100
              }
            ),
          ])
        ])
      ).start()
    }
    animationDef()
  }, [animationRef])
  const rotateZ = animationRef.current.rotateZ.interpolate({
    inputRange: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    outputRange: ['-100deg', '-424deg', '-500deg', '-784deg', '-820deg'],
  })
  return (
    <Animated.View style={[LoadingStyles.wrap, { transform: [{ rotate: rotateZ }] }]}>
      <Svg style={LoadingStyles.circleBox}>
        <Circle
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r="45%"
          strokeWidth="5"
          stroke="#f3f3f3"
          fill="none"
        ></Circle>
        <CircleAnimateClip
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r="45%"
          strokeWidth="5"
          strokeDasharray={2 * Math.PI * 60}
          strokeDashoffset={animationRef.current.strokeDashoffset as unknown as string}
          stroke={EStyleSheet.value('$primaryColor')}
          fill="none"
        ></CircleAnimateClip>
      </Svg>
    </Animated.View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `react-native animated api` dropping frames with high calculation on JS main thread, as I try to use `react-native-reanimated` to refactor animated code, it work well.

But, I still don't know how to optimize usage of `react-native animated api`